# I want to make a program that calculate a circle area in OOP style in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-3.7

Those are codes written in Python, and my intention is to make a program that calculates a circle area. But an error occurred. Please advise!

script.py

```
from circle import Circle

circle1 = circle(30)

print(circle1.cirArea())
```

circle.py

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def cirArea(self):
        return self.radius * self.radius * 3.14
```

Comment: What error occurred? Does changing `circle(30)` to `Circle(30)` fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You’ve got a typo when assigning the initialised class to a variable. It should be:

```
circle1 = Circle(30)
```

Not:

```
circle1 = circle(30)
```

Otherwise the code works fine, although there are improvements you could make. Something like:

```
import math
...
    def cirArea(self):
        return math.pi * (self.radius ** 2)
```

Rather than `self.radius * self.radius * 3.14`

Answer (score 0):

Let me fix the code

script.py

```
from circle import Circle

circle1 = Circle(30)

print(circle1.cirArea())
```

circle.py

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def cirArea(self):
        return self.radius * self.radius * 3.14
```

The problem is you typed "Circle", "circle" which is a module